# Formula - Cap width at 100%

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I have the following working just fine. Anything under 100 is taken as itself while more than that is capped at 100. While it works fine, I would like to write it as a maths formula for neatness. Any ideas?

```
var ceiling = 100;
var incrementSize = 10;
var width = ""

if (score*incrementSize<ceiling) 
{
    width = "" + incrementSize * score + "%";
}
else
{
    width = "" + ceiling + "%";
}

divj.style.width = width;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a ternary operation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Basic syntax is:

("condition to be evaluated")? "return if true" : "return if false"

```
divj.style.width = (score*incrementSize<ceiling)? incrementSize * score + "%" : ceiling + "%";
```

This'll reduce things down to just one line.

Comment: I used this. Very useful. Very Neat.